# How to get name manager in excel to check a cell in current worksheet

Tags: excel

I have a name manager formula that checks a specific cell in a worksheet. I want it to be able to check that specific cell in the worksheet that the name is written in, instead of the same table every time.

For example, I have two worksheets, Data1 and Data2. If I write the name into a cell in Data1, I want it to check cell D6 in the Data1 worksheet. However, if I write the name in Data2, I want it to check cell D6 in the Data2 worksheet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean a named range to reference the active sheet.

In the Name Manager enter **=!$B$2="MyName"**.  This will check cell B2 on the active sheet and return TRUE if it contains **MyName** - using just the exclamation mark tells it to use the activesheet.

Source:  Mike Rickson (http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=70832)

Comment: This did it! Thank you for this Darren.

Answer (score 0):

This works well, as long as you have either a name in Sheet1 or a name in Sheet2.

If there are names in both cells, this formula will always print out the one in Sheet2.

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="name","right name",If(Sheet2!A1="name","right name","false name))
```